# Windows Form Application - Save file from Web URL into Database

Tags: sql-server, winforms, visual-studio

I am currently trying to read a file from the Web and save this into my SQL Database but am experiencing difficulty in saving the file.  What is getting inserted into the database as the file data seems to be wrong so gives an error on trying to read it back from the database.  The following is the code I am using:

```
Dim objWReq As WebRequest
        Dim objWResp As WebResponse
        objWReq = HttpWebRequest.Create(CVDocumentURL)
        objWResp = objWReq.GetResponse()

        Dim objStream As System.IO.Stream
        objStream = objWResp.GetResponseStream


        Dim objData As Byte() = ReadFully(objStream)

        objWResp.Close()

        Dim ObjAdapter As New TableAdapters.Method
        ObjAdapter.InsertFile(ApplicationId, UserId, VacancyId, DateCreated, CoveringLetter, CVDocumentURL, Nothing, objWResp.ContentType, FileName, objWResp.ContentLength, objData)
```

On checking the properties of objData they all seem to be fine before doing the insert.  Does anyone know what is going wrong here?

Thanks